# put validation on Editable row Form using Angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in Anguarljs and working on Editable row form.In this form, when i am going to add row button then it's showing new row .but when i am going to add save button without entered data it's showing "empty",Not set" text in form.i wanted that some alert message should come if text box is empty or dropdown is not selected. please tell where should i change my code.how to perform validation in this form
below code

```
<div ng-controller="EditableRowCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr style="font-weight: bold">
      <td style="width:35%">Name</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Status</td>
      <td style="width:20%">Group</td>
      <td style="width:25%">Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>
        <!-- editable username (text with validation) -->
        <span editable-text="user.name" e-name="name" e-form="rowform" onbeforesave="checkName($data, user.id)" e-required>
          {{ user.name || 'empty' }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable status (select-local) -->
        <span editable-select="user.status" e-name="status" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="s.value as s.text for s in statuses">
          {{ showStatus(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- editable group (select-remote) -->
        <span editable-select="user.group" e-name="group" onshow="loadGroups()" e-form="rowform" e-ng-options="g.id as g.text for g in groups">
          {{ showGroup(user) }}
        </span>
      </td>
      <td style="white-space: nowrap">
        <!-- form -->
        <form editable-form name="rowform" onbeforesave="saveUser($data, user.id)" ng-show="rowform.$visible" class="form-buttons form-inline" shown="inserted == user">
          <button type="submit" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">
            save
          </button>
          <button type="button" ng-disabled="rowform.$waiting" ng-click="rowform.$cancel()" class="btn btn-default">
            cancel
          </button>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons" ng-show="!rowform.$visible">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="rowform.$show()">edit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeUser($index)">del</button>
        </div>  
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser()">Add row</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An angular form can be validated using attributes like `ng-minlength="3"` or `ng-required` inside the input fields.

Then you can check if the field is valid with `myForm.myInput.$valid`

There is an example on how are forms validated with angularjs

```
<script>
   angular.module('inputExample', [])
     .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
       $scope.user = {name: 'guest', last: 'visitor'};
     }]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">
    User name: <input type="text" name="userName" ng-model="user.name" required>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.userName.$error.required">
      Required!</span><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="user.last"
      ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="10">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.minlength">
      Too short!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.lastName.$error.maxlength">
      Too long!</span><br>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>user = {{user}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>myForm.userName.$valid = {{myForm.userName.$valid}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.userName.$error = {{myForm.userName.$error}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.lastName.$valid = {{myForm.lastName.$valid}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.lastName.$error = {{myForm.lastName.$error}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$error.minlength = {{!!myForm.$error.minlength}}</tt><br>
  <tt>myForm.$error.maxlength = {{!!myForm.$error.maxlength}}</tt><br>
</div>
```

Just read the documentation about forms https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

And about inputs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Comment: Thanks for reply.i am not asking for simple form validation.it's already done from my end.but problem in editable row.there i wanted to put validation on it not in simple form